# What factors influence the point at which a sampling distribution is said to be nearly normally distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, sample-size

What factors influence the point at which a sampling distribution is said to be nearly normally distributed?

*Note that the answer I am looking for is not sample size. I am asking what decides how big is the sample size can a sampling distribution to be said *nearly* normally distributed. Also, I am not looking for an answer saying the sampling distribution *is* normal when the sample size is $\infty$.